# Why am I getting warning: (near initialization for ‘ptr’) and segmentation fault at runtime when accsessing value at pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization

This is the following code:
Why it is giving segmentation fault when I try to access first value of array?
What are all this warnings?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5};//Is it not similar to char *ptr="Stackoverflow"?
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);// why Segmentation fault(core dumped) instead of 1
    return 0;
}

...
output:

warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] 
int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5};
^

warning: (near initialization for ‘ptr’) [enabled by default]
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
warning: (near initialization for ‘ptr’) [enabled by default]
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
warning: (near initialization for ‘ptr’) [enabled by default]
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
warning: (near initialization for ‘ptr’) [enabled by default]
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
warning: (near initialization for ‘ptr’) [enabled by default]
```

Comment: `int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5};` means `int *ptr = (int *)1;`, which makes no sense. (This is GCC extension, it is illegal in standard C.) If you want an array, use `int ptr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266987/int-nums-5-2-1-4-causes-a-segmentation-fault?newsletter=1&nlcode=537056%7c1ced)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code is invalid. It contains at least two *constraint violations*: it provides initializers for objects that don't exist, and it tries to use an initializer `1` (of type `int`) for an `int*` object. A compiler could (and IMHO should) simply reject it. gcc is being overly permissive by compiling your code after merely warning about the errors. The resulting code has undefined behavior.

```
const char *cptr = "Hello";
```

The above is valid. `"Hello"` is an expression of array type (specifically of type `char[6]`). In most contexts, including this one, such an expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's 0th element. Note that I've added `const` so the compiler will at least warn if I attempt to modify the data that `cptr` points to.

```
int *iptr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // invalid
```

This is invalid. You might expect that it's handled similarly to `cptr`. The problem is that `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` is not an expression; it's valid only in an initializer. It could be a valid initializer for an array object, but since it's not an expression, the array-to-pointer conversion rule doesn't apply.

Assuming your compiler supports C99 or later (specifically the *compound literal* feature), you can write:

```
int *iptr = (int[]){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

(This is not a cast; the syntax is similar, but the `{ ... }` is not an expression.)

The compound literal is an expression of array type, specifically `int[5]`, and the array-to-pointer conversion applies.

One caveat: A string literal creates an array object, and that object has *static storage duration*, meaning that it exists throughout the execution of the program. A compound literal creates an object with static storage duration only if it appears outside any function; inside a function, it creates an object with *automatic storage duration*, meaning that it ceases to exist when you reach the end of the current block. In this case, it's defined inside the `main` function, so it's not likely to be an issue. But it's something to watch out for. For example, this is safe:

```
const char *new_string(void) {
    const char *result = "hello";
    return result;
}
```

but this is not:

```
int *new_array(void) {
    int *result = (int[]){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    return result; /* BAD! */
}
```

because the array ceases to exist when you leave the function.  To avoid that, you can create the array object explicitly to make it static:

```
int *new_array(void) {
    static const int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int *result = arr; /* or &arr[0] */
    return result;     /* or "return arr;" */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> *//Is it not similar to char *ptr="Stackoverflow"?*

**TL;DR** No, it is not.

---

The used initializer, `{1,2,3,4,5}` is called a brace-enclosed initalizer which is supposed to initialize the values of the *type* of the elements. This is used for *aggregate or union type* type, like mentioned as in `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, *Initialization*

> the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace enclosed
>   list of initializers for the elements or named members.

Here, the initializer list contains all `int` values, and you're trying to initialize a `pointer` thought it. This is wrong.

Also, regarding the ***scalar type***, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.5

> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types.[...]

and the ***aggregate types***

> [...]Array and
>   structure types are collectively called aggregate types.

There are many issues here, like

1. You're using `int` value to initialize an `int *`.
2. You're ending up supplying a  *brace enclosed list* containing more than one initializer element for a *scalar* object.

So, later in your code,

```
 printf("%d\n",*ptr);
```

is essentially an *invalid memory access*, which  invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The segmentation fault is one of the many side-effects.

Coming to the point of the comment,

> *char *ptr="Stackoverflow"?*

In case of `char *ptr="Stackoverflow";`, here, `"Stackoverflow"` is called a *string literal* and `ptr` is initalized with the base address of the *string literal*.

---

Solution:

You need to have an *array* of `int`s which you can initialize using the brace-enclosed initializer. Something along the line of

```
 int ptr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

will be valid. Then you can use it like

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d\t", *(ptr+i));
```

Comment: I would add that OP's code actually initializes `int *ptr` with value `1`, because it's first in the list.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Only if you ignore the constraint violations of (a) using the `int` value `1` to initialize a pointer, and (b) providing initializers for objects that don't exist. A conforming compiler could (and IMHO should) simply reject the code, meaning that nothing is initialized to anything. There is no language rule that says that if there are too many initializers, the excess ones are ignored.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, a conforming compiler must reject the code, and this is how gcc with `-pedantic-errors` acts. But without this flag it only emits some warnings and puts `1` into the pointer. (I should have mentioned that I'm talking about gcc behaviour without the flag.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: No, a conforming compiler is merely required to issue a diagnostic. The only thing a conforming compiler is actually required to fail to compile is a `#error` directive.

Comment: @KeithThompson Oops. Thanks. I learn something new about C++ every day!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I was actually referring to rules in the C standard, but I think C++ is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer is a scalar data type and standard says that (C11-6.7.9):

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a **single expression**, optionally enclosed in braces.

You can't initialize a scalar data type with brace enclosed initializer having more than one expressions.

In case of

```
char *ptr="Stackoverflow";
```

`ptr` is pointing to the object with type *array of char* (look at standard C11:§6.7.9/11). It just initializes `ptr` to the start of the address of string literal.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int ptr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};//Is it not similar to char *ptr="Stackoverflow"?
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);// why Segmentation fault(core dumped) instead of 1
    return 0;
}
```

In the original code:

```
int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

`{1,2,3,4,5}` won't initialize an integer array. String initialization is a special case which is not applicable over other types.

So this code will initialize an integer pointer which will point to memoery address 0x00000001 (first one in the initializer block)

This address is out of program scope and thus segmentation error came into picture.

Comment: Yes. An array of int is **not** the same thing (type) as a pointer to int. (Whereas a literal string **is** of type pointer to char.)

Comment: @JeffY You are commenting on the wrong post. This answer simply copied over the `//` comments from the original question.

Comment: This answer is good, but could be better if it specified *why* this code is good and the original one was bad

Answer (score 0):

basically that line is invalid, the c compiler has tried to make sense of it but really cannot. You need the syntax here

[How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)

Summary

```
int myArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store values in an unitialised pointer. The value of the pointer must be attached to a memory location prior you can access it.
Just do some `malloc` before:

```
int $ptr;
ptr = malloc( 5* sizeof(int)); // since you have 5 values and then you can initialize your data
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {

(*ptr+i) = (i+1);

}
```