# Precedence of assignment

Tags: c, operators

In c ,

```
main()   {
 int a = (1,2,3,4);
  printf("%d",a); 
}
```

yields an output of

> 4

This is because comma(,)operator has a right to left precedence .
But

```
main()   {
int a = {1,2,3,4};
 printf("%d",a);
}
```

yields an output

> 1

anyone pls explain the logic behind this.
Thanks

Comment: What does `gcc -Wall` tell you?

Comment: I think that this is a [constraint violation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p2), and hence undefined behavior.

Comment: None of this looks remotely standard, nor correct as of 2017, or the past 30 years.

Comment: It is actually perfectly fine C. Nearly identical duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266987/int-nums-5-2-1-4-causes-a-segmentation-fault

Comment: @Lundin (replaced comment) -- I see it's trying to do this to a pointer, but this question doesn't discuss whether this is allowed. See my answer, is my interpretation of §6.7.9 -- 2 wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`{1,2,3,4}` is the syntax for an *initializer*, used to initialize something that has more than one value, like an array or a struct. So the commas inside it are not *operators*, they are just part of the initializer syntax.

When initializing, C uses the values from the initializer *from the left*. As you initialize a single scalar variable, only one element is needed.

Your compiler is supposed to tell you that this code doesn't make sense:

```
x.c:2:12: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 int a = {1,2,3,4};
            ^
```

---

I should add that this code violates a constraint of the standard, see C11 draft N1570, § 6.7.9 -- 2:

> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.

This requires the compiler to emit a diagnostic when compiling such broken code.

From the same paragraph is the following rule (number 17):

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no
>   designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
>   to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure
>   members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union.1

So your compiler decides to do the "*next closest*" thing to the standard and just use the first value you provide.

Comment: gcc issues the warning even without -Wall option.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it is required to do so (constraint violation), I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's an **initializer** (usually used for *arrays*), but you are not using it wisely, didn't your compiler tell you?

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
main.c:2:13: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 int a = {1,2,3,4};
            ^
```

The precedence here is from left to right, and since you have only one element to initialize, one element is chosen from the initializer (that is 1 in this case).

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces mean initialization of the variable, mostly useful for *arrays*.

In your case, compiling with gcc yields:

```
test.c:6:12: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 int a = {1,2,3,4};
            ^
```

(same for 3 & 4)

Means that only value `1` is useful for your case (it's a scalar)